# Having trouble formatting this JSON data from the server

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

I'm creating a section of a site in Angular JS that displays some reporting data from the server. Since I'm displaying it in a table I need it in a format that can easily be displayed with ng-repeat.

I therefore need to translate JSON data from the server into a JavaScript object. I've got the target format of the data I want, an object that uses the names of the 'Donor Programs' as keys, and as their values an array of objects that each correspond to a month. Each of the objects has the name of the month, the amount of people who registered on the site, the amount of those people who donated, and the total amount donated.

I'm just having a really hard time iterating through the JSON and getting it to translate to that format. Can someone have a look? I've included both the server data I'm getting as well as how I'm trying to format it. Thanks.

**Server Data:**

```
$scope.serverData = {
"registration_by_month": [
    {
        "month": "November 2015",
        "registration_program": "Donor Program 1",
        "count": 3
    },
    {
        "month": "November 2015",
        "registration_program": "Donor Program 2",
        "count": 4
    },
    {
        "month": "December 2015",
        "registration_program": "Donor Program 1",
        "count": 5
    },
    {
        "month": "December 2015",
        "registration_program": "Donor Program 2",
        "count": 6
    }
],

"donors_by_month": [
    {
        "month": "November 2015",
        "registration_program": "Donor Program 1",
        "count": 2
    },
    {
        "month": "November 2015",
        "registration_program": "Donor Program 2",
        "count": 1
    },
    {
        "month": "December 2015",
        "registration_program": "Donor Program 1",
        "count": 2
    },
    {
        "month": "December 2015",
        "registration_program": "Donor Program 2",
        "count": 1
    }
],

"donated_amount_by_month": [
    {
        "month": "November 2015",
        "registration_program": "Donor Program 1",
        "amount": 100
    },
    {
        "month": "November 2015",
        "registration_program": "Donor Program 2",
        "amount": 200
    },
    {
        "month": "December 2015",
        "registration_program": "Donor Program 1",
        "amount": 50
    },
    {
        "month": "December 2015",
        "registration_program": "Donor Program 2",
        "amount": 40
    }
]
```

};

**Target Data:**

```
$scope.targetData = {
"Donor Program 1": [{month:"November 2015", registered:3, donors:2, donated_amount:100},{month:"December 2015", registered:4, donors:1, donated_amount:200}],
"Donor Program 2:": [{month:"November 2015", registered:5, donors:2, donated_amount:50},{month:"December 2015",registered:6, donors:1, donated_amount:40}]
```

};

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try like this

```
 var temp = {};
 data.registration_by_month.forEach(function (x) {
     if (!temp[x.registration_program]) {
         temp[x.registration_program] = [];
     }
     var dtmon = data.donors_by_month.find(function (y) {
         return y.registration_program == x.registration_program;
     });
     var dnmon = data.donated_amount_by_month.find(function (y) {
         return y.registration_program == x.registration_program;
     });
     temp[x.registration_program].push({
             month: x.month,
             registered: x.count,
             donors: dtmon ? dtmon.count : 0,
             donated_amount: dnmon ? dnmon.amount : 0
     });

 });
console.log(temp);
```

**[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/aiubian/044c8g2d/)**

**EDIT**

[**.find**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) is not supported in IE and opera.

You can try **[.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)** instead

Like this

```
 var temp = {};
 data.registration_by_month.forEach(function (x) {
     if (!temp[x.registration_program]) {
         temp[x.registration_program] = [];
     }
     var dtmon = data.donors_by_month.filter(function (y) {
         return y.registration_program == x.registration_program;
     });
     var dnmon = data.donated_amount_by_month.filter(function (y) {
         return y.registration_program == x.registration_program;
     });
     temp[x.registration_program].push({
             month: x.month,
             registered: x.count,
             donors: dtmon.length > 0 ? dtmon[0].count : 0,
             donated_amount: dnmon.length > 0 ? dnmon[0].amount : 0
     });

 });
```

**[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/aiubian/8rL5xca1/)**

Comment: Wow... awesome. I wasted a couple hours with a couple nested loops and wasn't getting anywhere. Thank you!

Comment: Minor/potentially useful point if you're chained to older browsers by your requirements: you may not have native `forEach` or `find`. Angular comes with a `forEach` implementation, but look to underscore/lodash/pick your poison/brew your own for the `find` and similar